# Concatenating in php code

Tags: php, concatenation

I've tried several different variations of concatenating the input from the text boxes, but none of them worked. Can anyone help by show me how to concatenate all of these on one line (back to back)?

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="sample.php">

<p>My Information
<br />City State  <input type="text" name="item1" size="30">
<br />State Name   <input type="text" name="item2" size="30">
<br />County Name    <input type="text" name="item3" size="30">

</p>

<input type="submit" value="Submit Information">

</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php

print "<h4>Geographic Location<b/h4>>";
$filename = 'data/'.'sample.txt';
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');   //w opens the file for writing
$cntr = 1;
while(true)
{
    $item_name = 'item'.$cntr;
    $item = $_POST[$item_name];
    if (empty($item))
    {
        break;
    }
    $cntr++;
    print "Item: ".$item."<br />";
    $output_line = $item."\n";
    fwrite($fp, $output_line);
}
```

Comment: `$output_line .= $item." ";` i assume you ant a space between each

Comment: @Dagon No, that's not necessary. He's writing each line to the file inside the loop, so he doesn't need to concatenate them.

Comment: oh true that... although he should take the file write outside the loop

Comment: If you want them all on one line, why are you concatenating `\n`?

Comment: Also, why are you putting `<br/>` in a text file, that's for HTML.

Comment: thre `<br/>` is only displayed, its not written to the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming this is the whole form this can be greatly simplified, there is no need for any loop:

```
print "<h4>Geographic Location<b/h4>>";
$filename = 'data/'.'sample.txt';
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');   //w opens the file for writing
$output_line = $_POST['item1'].' '.$_POST['item2'].' '.$_POST['item3']; //create the string to write to file 
print "Item: ".$output_line."<br />"; //display to the user
fwrite($fp, $output_line); //write to the file
```

changing item 1-3 to more descriptive names is recommended